# print every nth line into a row using gawk

Tags: printing, awk, line, gawk

I have a very huge file in which I need to obtain every nth line and print it into a row.

My data:

```
1      937  4.320194
2      667  4.913314
3      934  1.783326
4      940  -0.299312
5      939  2.309559
6      936  3.229496
7      611  -1.41808
8      608  -1.154019
9      606  2.159683
10     549  0.767828
```

I want my data to look like this:

```
1      937  4.320194
3      934  1.783326
5      939  2.309559
7      611  -1.41808
9      606  2.159683
```

This is of course an example, I want every 10th line for my huge data file.  I tried this so far:

```
 NF == 6 {
     if(NR%10) {print;}
     }
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To print every second line, starting with the first:

```
awk 'NR%2==1' file.txt
```

To print every tenth line, starting with the tenth line:

```
awk 'NR%10==0' file.txt
```

---

To use this in a script, add the following to a file called `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    print "Processing file"
}

NR%10==0

END {
    print "Finished processing"
}
```

Then execute:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `awk 'NR%10==0' file.txt`?

Comment: @D.Shawley Yes you are correct. I should really read things through before answering! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much, I know it was a simple question but I couldn't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: If there anyway to execute this in a script?

Comment: HTH. Also, you don't need either the BEGIN or END blocks.

Answer (score 18):

With `sed`, you can do a lot of variations on this quite easily with the `first~step` command.  For instance:

```
# Odd lines
sed -n 1~2p file
# Every tenth line (10, 20, 30, ...)
sed -n 10~10p file
# Every tenth line (1, 11, 21, ...)
sed -n 1~10p file
# First plus every tenth (1, 10, 20, 30, ...)
sed -n -e 1p -e 10~10p file
```

Comment: @Gerard See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 9):

Piece of cake: `cat test.txt | awk 'NR % 10 == 1'`

Comment: That prints the line following every 10th line - lines 1, 11, 21, 31, etc.  You want lines where the modulus is zero instead of 1.

Comment: Well, why? This also prints every 10th line, starting with the first, and it matches with what is given as example.

Answer (score 2):

It's not (g)awk, but it'll work:

`cat myfile | grep ^[[:digit:]]*0[[:blank:]]` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it directly in command Prompt (Windows).

Put the gawk.exe file in the folder where the file is and start a command Prompt in the folder, and write

```
gawk "NR%n==x" oldfile.txt>newfile.txt
```

n is every n'th line you want to print and x is the starting line.

E.g n=10 and x=1, printing line 1,11,21,31,41......end line from the original file into the new file.

E.g n=20 and x=5, printing line 5,25,45,65......end line from the original file into the new file.