# How do i extract the text present in the 7th line of a file

Tags: shell, text, line, extract

How do i extract the text present in the 7th line of a file using shell script
For eg., I have sumthing like,

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
```

I need to print the text `stu`.

Can sumbdy help on this. Pls...

Comment: possible duplicate of [print every nth line into a row using gawk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968916/print-every-nth-line-into-a-row-using-gawk)

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash tool to get nth line from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==7' file
```

as `NR` refers to number of line.

Also in `sed`:

```
sed -n '7p' file
```

**Update** And even better ([thanks pixelbeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296916/how-do-i-extract-the-text-present-in-the-7th-line-of-a-file/17296953?noredirect=1#comment26483451_17296953http://))

```
sed -n '7{p;q}' file
```

#### Test to see how better is the second option:

Let's fill a file with 1,000,000 lines:

```
$ for i in {1..1000000}; do echo $i>>a; done
```

Now let's compare the time used by each `sed`:

```
$ time sed -n '3p' a
3

real    0m0.098s
user    0m0.084s
sys     0m0.008s
$ time sed -n '3{p;q}' a
3

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Which is 8 times faster!

```
$ echo "0.098 / 0.012" | bc
8
```

Comment: For sed I'd also get it to exit early, like: sed -n '7{p;q}'

Comment: Oh, that's a good improvement, @pixelbeat. I just updated my answer with a study of the performance of each command. Yours is way better!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to awk, there are many other utilities that can be composed to do this.  Here are a few more:

`head` and `tail`

```
head -n 7 file | tail -n 1
```

`perl`

```
perl -ne 'print if $.==7' file
```

`ruby` is actually identical to the `perl`

```
ruby -ne 'print if $.==7' file
```

There is probably a shorter way, here it is in python:

```
python -c "import sys; x=[l for l in sys.stdin]; sys.stdout.write(x[6])" < x
```

Comment: You missed `java` and `php` :) I think it is quite useful to have such broad options, although having tag:shell i don't think it is that necessary.

Comment: Java isn't very good at shell scripting (certainly not these kinds of 1-liners).  PHP isn't installed on my systems and I don't have much experience using it.  These are the things I typically use from my shell scripts.  Just offering options.  :)  Regards